# Checking Facebook URL using Jquery

Tags: jquery, regex, validation

I am adding a custom validator in jquery form validation. The custom validation is to check if the link is a valid Facebook URL link.

```
$.validator.addMethod(
    "validFacebookUrl",
    function(value, element) 
    {
        return this.optional(element) || value == value.match(/^(https?:\/\/)?((w{3}\.)?)facebook.com\/.*/);
    }
);
```

However, it is always giving me messagethat it is not a facebook url even if I use links like this:-

http://www.facebook.com/GajapatiKapilendra

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just escape the dot in facebook.com `^(https?:\/\/)?((w{3}\.)?)facebook\.com\/.*` https://regex101.com/r/foE4QK/1

Comment: _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers._

Comment: @mplungjan, I have done exactly the same, but somehow its still showing me a valid Facebook url as invalid. I think the problem is with the addValidator coding issue rather than the regex